# Trying to understand a scientific text about neurons and dopamine

Tags: neuroscience, dopamine

I'm in the process of reading https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1564381/ and I'm trying to understand how the predicting is done in the neuron.

What I distilled so far: A cell gets an input, it calculates a probability of reward(bliss potential i like to call it), if it could cause a reward it releases dopamine in a quantity of expected reward.

So right now I'm wondering,  what is the process that goes on to make that calculation. Which input variables does the neuron use to calculate the probability of a reward and how much dopamined to release?

Does it take account which synapses provided the input signals? Or is it the type of input signals? Or a combination of both? Is it the frequency inputs occur?

II need an explaination how the neuron calculates its "bliss potential" as i like to call it, in normal peoples english instead of academia english.

*P.s. I don't have an academic background.  I'm just interested in science related things without having a formal education.*